How to use a variable in Android build.gradle.kts
Root directory build.gradle.kts
extra.apply {
    // true: debug mode; false: distribute mode.
    set("isDebug", true)
}

Main module build.gradle.kts
val isDebug = rootProject.extra["isDebug"] as Boolean
if (isDebug) {
    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    }
} else {
    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
    }
}

I expect to control the content in "plugins" with a boolean variable.
